# Why can't I overload C++ conversion operators outside a class, as a non-member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, standards

This question has kind of been asked before but I feel the asker was hasty to call an answer correct when he never actually got a real answer. Maybe there is no reason why, and this needs to be put in the standard later, you tell me.
[What is the rationale to not allow overloading of C++ conversions operator with non-member functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733459/what-is-the-rationale-to-not-allow-overloading-of-c-conversions-operator-with)

I'm looking for the specific reason for this not being allowed as part of the design of the current standard. Basically, when you overload a cast operator to define an implicit conversion between two types, this overloaded definition has to be a member of the class that you're converting from, and not something outside a class. The obvious problem is that if you have types that you really can't modify for some reason but you want to implicitly convert between them for the sake of simplicity of syntax (despite the evils of implicit conversion) or because you have a bunch of other code, standard or custom that relies on implicit conversion...you can't do that if you can't add appropriate implicit conversions to the classes, so you need to use workarounds like regular functions for conversion that you would wrap around what would otherwise be the convenience of implicit conversion.

Also, is it...really possible that there would be a computational overhead to add these conversions outside a class? The way I see it, it would be easy for a compiler to, when going through to figure out what functions are available, associate external implicit conversion functions with the class they convert from so that the code is executed like it were part of that class as far as efficiency goes. The only downside would be the extra work it has to do to make the initial association, which should be almost nothing.

I will not take "because the standard says so" or "because implicit conversions are bad" as an answer. Somebody surely had a reason when they wrote the actual standard.

(I'm not a huge expert, I'm still learning the language.)

Edit, response:
Well, I imagine the situation could be like, yes you change the header file, but what you don't do is overwrite the existing one because that would be terrible. You would create a new header file based on the old one to accomodate the changes. The assumption would be that the old code is already compiled in an object file and changing the header just tells the compiler there's additional code somewhere else that you added. It wouldn't change what the old code does because it's already compiled and doesn't depend on that (i.e. some vendor handed you object code and a header). If I could modify and recompile the code I would be using the conversion for, then you couldn't make me write the conversion function externally, I wouldn't do it, it's too confusing. You wouldn't have to search every header randomly for the right definitions; if I was writing the code myself I would make a custom header with a highly visible section where the stuff I added to the vendor-supplied header is, and said header would be relatively obvious as to which one it was because it would be associated with the related types, and the other headers would be named by their original names so you would know they weren't changed. And you would have a corresponding file that contains only the conversion definitions, so my modifications would be self-contained, separated from the original object code, and relatively easy to find. Of course that's apart from the actual struggle of figuring out in the code which conversion function applies. I think you can find a variety of cases where that's easy enough to determine and natural enough to use where it makes sense to add on to an existing library like this for your own purposes. If I was using commercial code that I couldn't really modify and I saw a situation where what I was doing with it could be improved by using a conversion function to integrate it with some of my own stuff, I could see myself wanting to do this. Granted such things aren't obvious for a third person just reading a = b, they wouldn't know what was going on with my conversions just from that, but if you knew and it read nicely then it could work.

I appreciate the insight on how standards decisions tend to work, this is definitely a kind of fringe thing that you could ignore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Besides having non-explicit conversion operators e.g. `operator bool()` in a class, you can also have non-explicit constructors taking a single argument, in the class you are converting *to*, as a way of introducing a user-defined conversion. (Not mentioned in question)
2. As to why you cannot introduce user-defined conversions between two types `A` and `B` without modifying their definitions... well this would create chaos.

   If you can do this, then you can do it in a header file, and since introducing new user-defined conversions can change the meaning of code, it would mean that "old" code using only `A` and `B` could totally change what it is doing depending on if your header is then included before it, or something like this.

   It's already hard enough to figure out exactly what user-defined conversion sequences are taking place when things are going wrong, even with the restriction that the conversions have to be declared by one of the two types. If you literally have to search every single unrelated header file in full potentially to find these conversion function definitions it dramatically worsens the maintenance problem, and there doesn't appear to be any benefit to allowing this. I mean can you give a non-contrived example where this language feature would help you make the implementation of something much simpler or easier to read?

   In general, I think programmers like the idea that to figure out what a line `a = b;` does, they just have to read the definition of the type of `a` and the type of `b` and go from there... it's potentially ugly and painful if you start allowing these "gotcha" conversions that are harder to know about.

   I guess you could say the same thing with regards to `operator <<` being used for streaming... but with user-defined conversions its more serious since it can potentially affect *any* line of code where an object of that type is being passed as a parameter.

Also, I don't think you should necessarily expect to find a well-thought out reason, not everything that is feasible for compilers to implement is permitted by the standard. Committee tends to be conservative and seek consensus, so "no one really cared about feature X enough to fight for it" is probably as good an explanation as you will find about why feature X is not available.

[Why is initialization of a constant dependent type in a template parameter list disallowed by the standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104890/why-is-initialization-of-a-constant-dependent-type-in-a-template-parameter-list)

Answer to that question suggests a common reason for a feature not being available:

> 3. Legacy: the feature was left out in the first place and now we've built a lot without it that it's almost forgotten (see partial function template specialization).

Comment: I don't really know how to give long replies in the comments section, so I edited my original post at the top